# How to send file client to client python 3

Tags: python-3.x, file, server, client, send

I reasearched about this topic but no results. I have created a client to client communication in python but I need to know how to send a file from one to the other by inserting the file path in the console.

```
def send_file(path):
    file = open(path, "r")
    msg = file.readline()
    while msg:
        signature = signing_key.sign(msg.encode(), encoding="hex")
        msg = msg + "~" + signature.decode()
        client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
        msg = file.readline()
    file.close()

def receive_file(msg):
    file = open("new.txt", "w")
    file.write(msg)
    file.close()
```

EDIT:
1.SERVER

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Server for multithreaded (asynchronous) chat application."""
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def accept_incoming_connections():
    """Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
        print("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
        client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave!", "utf8"))
        addresses[client] = client_address
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()


def handle_client(client):  # Takes client socket as argument.
    """Handles a single client connection."""

    name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
    welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % name
    client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
    msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
    broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    clients[client] = name

    while True:
        msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if msg != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
            broadcast(msg, name + ": ")
        else:
            client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
            client.close()
            del clients[client]
            broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % name, "utf8"))
            break


def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):  # prefix is for name identification.
    """Broadcasts a message to all the clients."""
    print(msg)
    for sock in clients:
        sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8") + msg)


clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

2:THIS IS THE CLIENT WHERE WE CAN RUN MULTIPLE INSTANCES OF CLIENTS, SO THE CONNECTION WILL BE CLIENT TO CLIENT USING THE SERVER AS A MIDDLEWARE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Script for Tkinter GUI chat client."""
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread

import tkinter


def receive():
    """Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            msg_list.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break


def send(event=None):  # event is passed by binders.
    """Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = my_msg.get()
    my_msg.set("")  # Clears input field.
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    if "/" in msg:
        send_file(msg)
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        top.quit()


def on_closing(event=None):
    """This function is to be called when the window is closed."""
    my_msg.set("{quit}")
    send()


def send_file(path):
    file = open('file.txt', "r")
    msg = file.readline()
    while msg:
        client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
        msg = file.readline()
    file.close()


def receive_file(msg):
    file = open("new.txt", "w")
    file.write(msg)
    file.close()


top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chatter")

messages_frame = tkinter.Frame(top)
my_msg = tkinter.StringVar()  # For the messages to be sent.
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(messages_frame)  # To navigate through past messages.
# Following will contain the messages.
msg_list = tkinter.Listbox(messages_frame, height=15, width=50, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)
msg_list.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)
msg_list.pack()
messages_frame.pack()

entry_field = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=my_msg)
entry_field.bind("<Return>", send)
entry_field.pack()
send_button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=send)
send_button.pack()

top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

#----Now comes the sockets part----
HOST = input('Enter host: ')
PORT = input('Enter port: ')
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()
tkinter.mainloop()  # Starts GUI execution.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say where is your problem. I think that the `msg` in the receive_file function is not complete file but only a part of it. The reason behind it is the `socket.recv` method unlike `read()` doesn't return 'all' data but only part which was received until the call (and there is some buffer limitation which is not important atm.). So you need to first receive all data and then write then into file.

For that you have to ways how to do it. The first just save all incoming data into memory until the connection is closed. The second first send information how big file the sender sending and then read data until the transfer is complete. The second approach has advantage that you can use the same connection for multiple files.

Here is complete server-client implementation (implementing the second way):

```
#send_recv.py
import struct
import sys
import socket

def send_file(path, sock):
    with open(path, "rb") as file:
        # First read file into memory
        content = file.read()
        # Now calculate size and convert it into 8-byte long bytes sequence
        size = struct.pack("<Q", len(content))
        # Send the file size
        sock.send(size)
        # Send the file
        sock.send(content)


def recv_file(path, sock):
    with open(path, "wb") as file:
        # Receive size of file
        received = sock.recv(8)
        # Convert the 8-byte long sequence into integer
        size, = struct.unpack("<Q", received)
        # Start receiving data until the whole file is received
        received = 0
        while received < size:
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            file.write(data)
            received += len(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with socket.socket() as s:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        if sys.argv[1] == "-s":
            s.bind(("localhost", 55000))
            s.listen(1)
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            with conn:
                print("Sending file {}".format(sys.argv[2]))
                send_file(sys.argv[2], conn)
        elif sys.argv[1] == "-c":
            s.connect(("localhost", 55000))
            print("Receiving into file {}".format(sys.argv[2]))
            recv_file(sys.argv[2], s)
```

Usage:

- `python3 send_recv.py -s some_file` - starts server sending file
- `python3 send_recv.py -c some_file` - starts client receiving file

Note: tested with Python 3.6

Also you should add some error checking.

Comment: it throws an error: if sys.argv[1] == "-s":
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I will post my whole aplication above so you take a look!